# How to convert a numpy array to leveldb or lmdb format

Tags: python, numpy, pycaffe, leveldb, lmdb

I'm trying to convert a numpy array that was created using `pylearn2` into `leveldb/lmdb` so that I can use in `Caffe`.
[This is the script](https://github.com/lisa-lab/pylearn2/blob/master/pylearn2/scripts/datasets/make_cifar10_gcn_whitened.py) that I used to created the dataset. 
After running this script, couple of files are generated, among which there are `test.pkl`, `test.npy`, `train.pkl`, `train.npy`
I dont know if there is a direct way for converting to `leveldb/lmdb`, so assuming there is no way, I need to be able to read each image and its corresponding label, so that I can then save it into a `leveldb/lmdb` database.
I was told I need  to use the pickle file for reading since it provides a dictionary like structure. However, trying to do

```
import cPickle as pickle
pickle.load( open( "N:/pylearn2-master/datasets/cifar10/pylearn2_gcn_whitened/test.pkl", "rb" ) )
```

outputs
 `<pylearn2.datasets.cifar10.CIFAR10 at 0xde605f8>`
and I dont know what the correct way of accessing the items in a pickle file is and or whether I need to read from the numpy array directly.